# HTML to WordPress menu register, but link doesn't work

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

All the coding is OK, but the menu links do not work.

```
 <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->


<?php 
wp_nav_menu( 
    array( 
        'theme_location' => 'main-menu', 
        'container' => 'div', 
        'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right',
        'container_id' => 'menu', 
        'container_class' => 'collapse navbar-collapse' 
    )
);

------------------------------------------------------------------------
// add menu support and fallback menu if menu doesn't exist

function wpj_register_menu() {
    if (function_exists('register_nav_menu')) {
        register_nav_menu( 'main-menu', __( 'Main Menu', 'brightpage' ) );
    }
}
function wpj_default_menu() {
    echo '<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">';
    if ('page' != get_option('show_on_front')) {
        echo '<li><a href="'. home_url() . '/">Home</a></li>';
    }
    wp_list_pages('title_li=');
    echo '</ul>';
}
add_action('init', 'wpj_register_menu');
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: please format your code and question properly.

Comment: Can you clarify "doesn't work"? What _does_ happen with them? Do your actions get called at all?